# How best to use crmApi result within angularJs controller?

Tags: javascript, angular

Referring to the snippet below, how do I get the controller function (DashboardController) to 'wait' for the return from crmApi? I've debugged enough to know crmApi returns the results I like, but DashboardController exits before I set self.user.

I'm weak on promises, but perhaps I also need to find a better place to call crmApi? Is it a better practice to call crmApi within, e.g., angular.module('tournament').config(['$routeProvider' ...

angular.module('tournament').component('dashboard', {
templateUrl: '~/tournament/dashboard/dashboard.template.html',
controller: ['$routeParams', 'crmApi',
function DashboardController($routeParams, crmApi) {
var self = this;

```
  // e.g., dashboard/43
  if ($routeParams.userId !== undefined) self.userId = $routeParams.userId;

  self.user = crmApi('Contact', 'getsingle', {
    "sequential": 1,
    "return": ["display_name","modified_date"],
    "id": self.userId
    }).then(
        // Success
        function(result) { 
            return result; // How can I get self.user to 'wait' for this return?
        },
        // Failure
        function (error) { 
            CRM.alert(ts('Could not get user record ID of %1, error = %2', {1: userId, 2: error}),ts('Not Found'),'error'); 
        }
    );
}
```

]
});

Answer (score 1):

I finally remembered that promises return callbacks. So, instead of

```
return result
```

in the then of the crmApi promise, using

```
self.user result
```

does exactly what I need.